# force:source:deploy is not a sfdx command error while trying to deploy through Jenkins

Tags: salesforcedx, jenkins

I am trying to setup the CI / CD through Jenkins. I have installed the Jenkins locally and have created a new pipeline project. I am able to successfully authenticate the org using JWT. However, i am seeing the error 'force:source:deploy is not a sfdx command' while the Jenkins tries to deploy. I am able to deploy through the command prompt using 'force:source:deploy'. Any help is appreciated. Below is the groovy code i am using to deploy :

## !groovy

import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
node {

```
def BUILD_NUMBER=env.BUILD_NUMBER
def RUN_ARTIFACT_DIR="tests/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
def SFDC_USERNAME

def HUB_ORG=env.HUB_ORG_DEV
def SFDC_HOST = env.SFDC_HOST_DEV
def JWT_KEY_CRED_ID = env.JWT_CRED_ID_DEV
def CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY=env.CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY_DEV

println 'KEY IS' 
println JWT_KEY_CRED_ID
println HUB_ORG
println SFDC_HOST
println CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY
def toolbelt = tool 'toolbelt'

stage('checkout source') {
    // when running in multi-branch job, one must issue this command
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "refs/heads/${BRANCH}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'Target_Dir']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'GIT_URL']]])
}

withCredentials([file(credentialsId: JWT_KEY_CRED_ID, variable: 'jwt_key_file')]) {
    stage('Deploye Code') {
        rc = bat returnStatus: true, script: "\"${toolbelt}\\sfdx\" force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid ${CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY} --username ${HUB_ORG} --jwtkeyfile \"${jwt_key_file}\" --setdefaultdevhubusername --instanceurl ${SFDC_HOST}"
        
        if (rc != 0) { error 'hub org authorization failed' }

        println rc
          
        println('Hello from a Job DSL script!')

        // need to pull out assigned username
        rmsg = bat returnStdout: true, script: "\"${toolbelt}\\sfdx\" force:source:deploy -d --checkonly --manifest manifest/package.xml -u ${HUB_ORG}"
          
        printf rmsg
        println('Hello from a Job DSL script!')
        println(rmsg)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you installed the custom tool plugin and configured the sfdx path? https://medium.com/@r.kurchenko/install-salesforcedx-cli-for-jenkins-builds-2e89495cc80b

Comment: Yes, I have installed the plugin and configured the sfdx path. I have the following version of CLI installed : sfdx-cli/7.48.0-a71f8c6899 win32-x64 node-v10.15.3. However, when i am trying to output the version in groovy code, it is showing the version as sfdx-cli/6.21.0-9db990b3c9 (windows-x64) node-v8.9.4